# How to stop Mac Maverick(10.9) App (aquamacs) startup crash cycle

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, aquamacs

Maverick appears to crash my Macbook pro coming out of sleep.
It recently crashed and after verifying the disks and startup again, Aquamacs no longer would run in one of my accounts.   I have 2 different admin accounts on my Mac.  In one account Aquamacs runs just fine.  In the other account, even after removing from /Applications and running from the .app in a newly downloaded .dmg  file, Aquamacs continues to crash.

I probably need to delete some file somewhere, but I don't know where.
I looked in /Library/Application Support/CrashReporter and found old, non aquamacs files which I removed.  I temporarily moved  SubmitDiagInfo.domains and DiagnosticMessagesHistory.plist to no effect.

The sequence goes like this:

Problem Report for Auaqmacs window:

**Aquamacs quit unexpectedly**

Click Reopen to open the application again.  This report will be sent to Apple automatically.

Problem Details and System Configuration:

```
Process:         Aquamacs [6532]
Path:            /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs
Identifier:      org.gnu.Aquamacs
Version:         2.5 (2.5.1371164793)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [458]
Responsible:     Aquamacs [6532]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2013-11-02 17:10:20.831 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  4E3149C4-C038-4097-8F05-652060A7760A


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000024

VM Regions Near 0x24:
--> __PAGEZERO             0000000000000000-0000000000001000 [    4K] ---/--- SM=NUL  /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-00000000001bb000 [ 1768K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95636286 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x956345ec kill$UNIX2003 + 32
2   org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x000976ca fatal_error_signal + 314
3   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x930acdeb _sigtramp + 43
4   ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9a141340 abort + 155
6   org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001793c2 ns_term_shutdown + 98
7   org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00095a13 shut_down_emacs + 243
8   org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0009768e fatal_error_signal + 254
9   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x930acdeb _sigtramp + 43
10  ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
11  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00030ea2 move_it_in_display_line_to + 674
12  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00031f4c move_it_to + 508
13  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0003c294 move_it_vertically + 100
14  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0004c4f3 Fwindow_end + 339
15  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00111303 Ffuncall + 707
16  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0014b48e Fbyte_code + 926
17  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001132ed funcall_lambda + 573
18  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001114f8 Ffuncall + 1208
19  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00113805 call1 + 37
20  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0011e9d4 mapcar1 + 772
21  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0011b18d Fmapc + 77
22  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00111303 Ffuncall + 707
23  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0014b48e Fbyte_code + 926
24  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001132ed funcall_lambda + 573
25  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001114f8 Ffuncall + 1208
26  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0014b48e Fbyte_code + 926
27  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001132ed funcall_lambda + 573
28  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001114f8 Ffuncall + 1208
29  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00113b21 run_hook_with_args + 529
30  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00111698 Frun_hooks + 56
31  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00111303 Ffuncall + 707
32  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00113805 call1 + 37
33  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0009c644 safe_run_hooks_1 + 52
34  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001122b4 internal_condition_case + 228
35  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x000a2b4d command_loop_1 + 349
36  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x001122b4 internal_condition_case + 228
37  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x000a29d5 command_loop_2 + 69
38  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00112383 internal_catch + 179
39  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x000a4d30 command_loop + 112
40  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x000a51ad recursive_edit_1 + 157
41  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x0009a47c Frecursive_edit + 380
42  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x00097556 main + 5590
43  org.gnu.Aquamacs                0x000031a5 start + 53

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637992 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x93a188bd _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x93a18556 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95631f7a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9563116c mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91deef69 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91dee541 __CFRunLoopRun + 1393
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91dedd5a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x91dedbbb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x97713f18 _NSEventThread + 283
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x983145fb _pthread_body + 144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98314485 _pthread_start + 130
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cf2 thread_start + 34

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x95637046 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98315dcf _pthread_wqthread + 372
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x98319cce start_wqthread + 30

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x00000006  ecx: 0xbfffca1c  edx: 0x95636286
  edi: 0x0045b2b0  esi: 0x00000006  ebp: 0xbfffca38  esp: 0xbfffca1c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000282  eip: 0x95636286   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xa171bcf4

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x000c0025
Trap Number:     132
```

Regardless of clicking OK or Reopen, Aquamacs will fail again.  I click OK.
I click /Applications/Aquamacs.app and get pop up:

```
The last time you opened Aquamacs, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again? 
If you choose not to reopen windows, you may have to open and position the windows yourself.
```

I click "Don't Reopen" (although same thing happens if click Reopen):

Using QuickTime NewScreenRecording I can see that an empty Aquamacs window opens for < 1 second, before the Problem report for Aquamacs occurs again.
And so the cycle continues.

I don't believe this is an Aquamacs problem as I have re-installed and it runs fine in the other account on the same Mac.
I believe this is some Maverick problem either due to crash reporting or some other file issue.

Any help of suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: actually most app are like that right now, i have problems with transmit, google chrome, safari and mail ... :S